# Firebase not connecting with React Application - Permission denied - Checked all question online on this no solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Trying to connect my react application with Firebase getting the error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: permission_denied at /tests: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

I have read all the answers and everything seems correct an anybody please take a look at whats going wrong.

When I test rule in the simulator with 
simulator `type = get`
simulator location  = `database/tests` it is showing me success output.

**May I am not using ref properly**

Inside React app -
Package I am using -     `"firebase": "^5.4.2",`

React code
**1.Config.js File**

```
// Initialize Firebase
import firebase from 'firebase';
const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
};
const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config)
export { fire }
```

2. **In my container component**

```
import { fire } from '../../Config/Config';

componentWillMount() {

   let testRef = fire.database().ref().child('tests');

   //also tried this
   //let testRef = fire.database().ref('tests');

   console.log('testRef', testRef)
   testRef.once("value").then((f) => {
   console.log(f);
  });
 }
```

3. **Rules in my firebase account**

```
service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
           allow read, write: if true;
        }
      }
    }
```

4. Data in **tests** node

[image: Image representing how node is present in my databse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your firebase rules suggest you use the [Firestore database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore?authuser=0) but your query is written for fetching data from [Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database?authuser=0)

So your testRef should be like so:

```
var testRef = fire.firestore().collection("tests");
```

and you can get all documents from it like so:

```
testRef
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

You should also consider using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) for your react-native project cause it seems to me you're using the web library

Comment: Thanks needsleep - you helped a lot.I read all from here --- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#once .   Can you tell me from which api I should read if not from here... I am making an webapp and not react native but thanks for sharing your great knowledge

Comment: I'm glad it helped :). I would first start reading the get started / how to add and fetch data section of the firestore database here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0 and then the API reference here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore?authuser=0. The API for react-native is pretty much the same as the Web so you'll be fine. Good luck!